# How to show one dialog on any screen when completing an achievement?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an achievement screen. I need when the user is on another screen (it can be any screen) to show a dialog that the achievement has been completed. I can display the dialog in a specific place where I write it, but how can I make the alert appear on any screen, even where I do not call it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all make a widget for dialog as like as below

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class MyAlertDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String content;

  MyAlertDialog({
    required this.title,
    required this.content,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(
          this.title,
        ),
        content: Container(
          height: 100,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(
                  this.content,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,

                child: MaterialButton(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  height: 50,
                  child: Text('dismiss', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Call the above widget where you need

```
showDialog(
                    barrierDismissible: true,
                    context: context,
                    builder: (
                        c,
                        ) {
                      return MyAlertDialog(title: 'Title ', content: 'Dialog content');
                    });
```